# How to inject a dll into the game process to execute dll function using game's lua engine?

Tags: dll, lua, code-injection

The game MDK 2 uses Lua as a script engine. What I want is to create a DLL that could be injected into the game and could add new Lua functions into the game those can be executed from the game script.
Is it even possible?

Comment: Possible in Lua 5.1

Comment: Can you just replace LUA.DLL with your own?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff What if I can't replace lua.dll because it's somehow built into the game? Do I have to reverse-engineer the game?

Comment: There is a well-known [exploit](https://gist.github.com/corsix/6575486)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Are there any ways to use this exploit on lua 3.1?

Comment: No, this exploit is only for 5.1.  Lua 3.1 is from 1998 year!  Is the game very old?

Comment: Yes, it is :) I want to create a multiplayer mod for the game, but I need to be able to call network methods from the game Lua scripts. Is reverse-engineering the only way to do it?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Maybe there is a way to hook Lua functions and somehow do what I want?

Comment: Lua 3.1 source code is [available](http://www.lua.org/versions.html).  Probably you should find and patch `lua_open` function in game exe.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica The game is MDK 2

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Can I do it with basic knowledge in code injection?

Comment: Yes, if you can edit .exe to modify the machine code.  You also have to know how to expose C functions to Lua scripts (read Lua manual).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff How can I find lua_open in the code? And could I replace the game's Lua library with my modified one somehow?

Comment: `could I replace the game's Lua library with my modified one` Why replacing?  You should ADD new functions to Lua globals, it should be done after `lua_open` finished. `How can I find lua_open` - with a debugger/disassembler :-) Ask on [RE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I thought that by replacing a library with mine I could make the game be able to use my modified library like it is it's own. Thank you for your answers, I will ask on RE.

Comment: I'm only vaguely aware of the complexities of patching executables, but what you want *should* be doable with some tutorials and a good understanding of how computers execute code.